# Why is adding a Firestore listener when a button is clicked so slow in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Electron/React app that stores data in Cloud Firestore.  I am using the Firebase Node.JS SDK.  I have 3 collections in my Firestore data structure, which is the following: Categories > (Collection of categories) > Subcategories > (Collection of subcategories) > Items > (Collection of items).  I have added a listener to the root Categories collection in my component's `componentDidMount` method, which is working.  What I am trying to do is add a listener to a specific Subcategory collection when a user clicks on a category.  I have repeated the same code for the subcategory listener as I have for the category listener, but it takes between 15-20 seconds for the subcategory listener to fire, even though the listener on the root Category collection fires almost instantly.  I've verified with `console.log` statements that the `onClick` handler is called as soon as a Category is clicked, but the code inside the `onSnapshot` block does not run until a full 15-20 seconds after the Category is clicked.  Additionally, each subcategory collection has less documents than the category collection, so I know it's not a loading issue.  Is my code faulty in some way?  If not, is there a way to force a Firestore collection listener to fire immediately after it is initialized?  Would it be a better idea to only use a listener on the root collection and manage the fetching of the sub-collections manually?  Here is my code -

In `AllInventory.tsx` (root component for our purposes):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MaterialList from './MaterialList';
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { firebaseConfig } from './PrivateKeys';

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//I have tried swapping out any "firestore.something" statements with 
//"firebase.firestore().something" statements but that didn't seem to make a difference
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

let categoriesListener = () => {};
let subcategoriesListener = () => {};
let itemsListener = () => {};

export default class AllInventory extends Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      categoriesArr: [],
      subcategoriesArr: [],
      itemsArr: [],
      selectedCategory: "",
      selectedSubcategory: "",
      selectedItems: "",
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    //This listener works and fires immediately
    categoriesListener = firestore.collection("Categories").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      const categories: { name: string }[] = [];
      querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          categories.push({name: change.doc.id.toString()});
        }
      })
      this.setState({categoriesArr: categories});
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    //Remove all Firestore listeners
    categoriesListener();
    subcategoriesListener();
    itemsListener();
  }

  handleCategoryClicked = (category: string) => {
    console.log("This line executes right when the list item is clicked");
    //Remove current listener, if it exists
    subcategoriesListener();
    //Add new listener
    subcategoriesListener = firestore.collection("Categories").doc(category).collection("Subcategories").onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      console.log("This line takes 15-20 seconds to execute after the function is called");
      const subcategories: { name: string }[] = [];
      querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          subcategories.push({name: change.doc.id.toString()});
        }
      })
      this.setState({
        selectedCategory: category,
        subcategoriesArr: subcategories
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      categoriesArr,
      subcategoriesArr,
      itemsArr
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="flex-box-horizontal-base-div">
        <div className="hRow stretchV">
          <MaterialList {...this.state} contentType="categories" onItemClick={this.handleCategoryClicked}/>
        </div>
        <div className="hRow stretchV">
          <MaterialList {...this.state} contentType="subcategories"/>
        </div>
        <div className="hRow stretchV last">
          <MaterialList {...this.state} contentType="items"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In `MaterialList.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItem, { ListItemProps } from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';

//Theme and useStyles are only for changing the default font/color scheme for Material UI,
//so I haven't included them here as they are long functions

function MaterialListItem(props: any) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { name } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <MenuItem style={{whiteSpace: 'normal'}} onClick={() => props.onItemClick(name)}>
        <ListItemText primary={name}/>
      </MenuItem>
      <Divider className={classes.dividerColor}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function MaterialList(props: any) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { contentType } = props;

  switch (contentType) {
    case "categories":
      if (props.categoriesArr.length !== 0) {
        return (
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <List className={classes.root} component="nav">
              <Divider className={classes.dividerColor}/>
              {props.categoriesArr.map((item: { name: string }) => (
                <MaterialListItem name={item.name} key={item.name} onItemClick={props.onItemClick}/>
              ))}
            </List>
          </ThemeProvider>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <List className={classes.root} component="nav"/>
          </ThemeProvider>
        )
      }
    case "subcategories":
      if (props.subcategoriesArr.length !== 0) {
        return (
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <List className={classes.root} component="nav">
              <Divider className={classes.dividerColor}/>
              {props.subcategoriesArr.map((item: { name: string }) => (
                <MaterialListItem name={item.name} key={item.name}/>
              ))}
            </List>
          </ThemeProvider>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <List className={classes.root} component="nav"/>
          </ThemeProvider>
        )
      }
    case "items":
      if (props.itemsArr.length !== 0) {
        return (
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <List className={classes.root} component="nav">
              <Divider className={classes.dividerColor}/>
              {props.itemsArr.map((item: { name: string }) => (
                <MaterialListItem name={item.name} key={item.name}/>
              ))}
            </List>
          </ThemeProvider>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <List className={classes.root} component="nav"/>
          </ThemeProvider>
        )
      }
    default:
      return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <List className={classes.root} component="nav"/>
        </ThemeProvider>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: To get the help you need, you may consult https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase support helped me solve this issue.  It turns out I was using an outdated version of Webpack that was packaging Firebase as an external dependency instead of bundling it with all the other libraries I was using.  Once I updated Webpack and removed it from my list of external dependencies, my issue with long Firebase load times was resolved.